# Is it possible to override a laravel package view from another package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8, php-7.3

Is it possible to override package view from another package?
When you register a view path via
`loadViewsFrom('path/to/views', 'package')`
it will also look in
`/resources/views/vendor/package`
So you can override a view when using a package,
but is there a way to override a view within a different package?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Steps:

1. Publish the package views you want to override:

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Another\Package" --tag=views
   ```
2. Modify the published ones.
3. Place the modifications in a dir in your package, e.g.:

   ```
    /resources/vendor/another-package/views
   ```
4. Make it available for publishing. Add to your package's service provider boot():

   ```
   public function boot()
   {
       $this->publishes([
           __DIR__.'/resources/vendor/another-package/views' =>
           base_path('resources/views/vendor/another-package')
       ], 'views');
   }
   ```
5. Publish the modifications:

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Your\Package" --tag=views --force
   ```

Note: change `Another\Package` and `another-package` as necessary. Works well in Laravel 7.